# How to avoid a double borrow error in struct method

Tags: rust, hashmap, borrow-checker

I'm newish to Rust and I'm trying to figure out how to fix the `Trader.gateway_client` method in the snippet below. It is caused by a double borrow of a mutable. What would be the correct way to fix the code (without cloning the `self.gateway` string before).

```rust
use std::collections::{HashMap};


pub struct GatewayClient {
    gateway: String,
    strategy: String,
}


pub struct Trader {
    gateway_clients: HashMap<String, GatewayClient>,
    strategy: String,
}


impl GatewayClient {
    pub fn new(gateway: &str, strategy: &str) -> Self {
        GatewayClient {
            gateway: String::from(gateway),
            strategy: String::from(strategy),
        }
    }
}


impl Trader {
    pub fn new(strategy: &str) -> Self {
        Trader {
            gateway_clients: HashMap::default(),
            strategy: String::from(strategy),
        }
    }

    pub fn gateway_client(&mut self, gateway: &str) -> &mut GatewayClient {
        self.gateway_clients.entry(String::from(gateway)).or_insert_with(|| {
            GatewayClient::new(gateway, &self.strategy)
        })
    }
}
```

The error thrown by the compiler is

```
63 |       pub fn gateway_client(&mut self, gateway: &str) -> &mut GatewayClient {
   |                             - let's call the lifetime of this reference `'1`
64 |           self.gateway_clients.entry(String::from(gateway)).or_insert_with(|| {
   |           --------------------                                             ^^ immutable borrow occurs here
   |           |
   |  _________mutable borrow occurs here
   | |
65 | |             GatewayClient::new(gateway, &self.strategy)
   | |                                          ------------- second borrow occurs due to use of `self` in closure
66 | |         })
   | |__________- returning this value requires that `self.gateway_clients` is borrowed for `'1`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A way to get around the borrowing conflict would be to eliminate the second explicit borrow within the callback by extracting what you need from `self` outside of it.

```rust
    pub fn gateway_client(&mut self, gateway: &str) -> &mut GatewayClient {
        let strategy = &self.strategy;

        self.gateway_clients
            .entry(gateway.into())
            .or_insert_with(|| GatewayClient::new(gateway, strategy))
    }
```

This looks like it may be a second borrow against `self` within the callback, but the compiler accepts this.

**`.or_insert_with()` vs. `.or_insert()`**

A fix was suggested using `.or_insert()`, but your choice to use `.or_insert_with()` is correct.

The advantage of using `.or_insert_with()` over `.or_insert()` in this case is the callback only gets executed if the entry doesn't exist. If using `.or_insert()`, `GatewayClient::new()` would be invoked whether or not the entry existed every time.

Answer (score 1):

You just didn't need to use `.or_insert_with` which allows to execute custom code via a closure. You just wanted to insert a value, and there's a method `.or_insert`, that accepts a value.

```
pub fn gateway_client(&mut self, gateway: &str) -> &mut GatewayClient {
    self.gateway_clients
        .entry(gateway.to_string())
        .or_insert(GatewayClient::new(gateway, &self.strategy))
}
```

Also if you'll ever want to get rid of a million of creations of new strings with `String::from(...)`, you can look towards `std::borrow::Cow` type

Comment: I believe the drawback would be that `GatewayClient::new()` is executed whether or not the entry exists when using `.or_insert()`, which might be why the OP used `.or_insert_with()`.